# Spring Data JPA Criteria API mockito order by id column failing with `Type must not be null! ` error

Tags: postgresql, junit, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, springmockito

Spring Data Jpa with criteria api Junits failed with `Type must not be null!` error, failure is mainly because of default sort order column i.e `id`(Long). Here I am using `**database view on entity class**`

ERROR:

```
Type must not be null!
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Type must not be null!
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:201)
    at org.springframework.data.util.ClassTypeInformation.from(ClassTypeInformation.java:69)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:331)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.QueryUtils.toJpaOrder(QueryUtils.java:600)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.QueryUtils.toOrders(QueryUtils.java:553)
```

Mocks used for test

```
        when(em.getCriteriaBuilder()).thenReturn(criteriaBuilder);
        when(criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Long.class)).thenReturn(this.countQuery);
        when(criteriaBuilder.createQuery(ExampleView.class)).thenReturn(criteriaQuery);
        when(criteriaQuery.from(ExampleView.class)).thenReturn(root);
        when(root.get(any(String.class))).thenReturn(path);
        when(criteriaBuilder.upper(path)).thenReturn(path);
        when(path.getJavaType()).thenReturn(Long.class);
        when(em.createQuery(criteriaQuery)).thenReturn(query);
        TypedQuery<Long> typedCountQuery = (TypedQuery<Long>) Mockito.mock(TypedQuery.class);
        when(em.createQuery(criteriaQuery)).thenReturn(query);
        when(em.createQuery(countQuery)).thenReturn(typedCountQuery);
        when(typedCountQuery.getSingleResult()).thenReturn(1L);
```

Can someone help me on this.

Comment: What the heck are you trying to achieve with this test? I'm pretty confident this is not a good way to achieve it.